# how to make the rule based anti-derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to make the following indefinite integration happen! is there any ways that I could make user-defined integration rules? Any help from anyone will be grateful!

[image]

Sincerely,

Li

Comment: Maybe if you wrote your equation in Mathemactia code and explained what you expect the input and the output to be, someone could help.

Comment: Hi bill, like what you suggested, I updated my question,hopefully, other people could give me some advice!

Comment: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IntegrateByParts

Comment: Hi Swish, I tried using the function you suggested ```ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"][Log[x]/x^2, x]```, while it does not work in MATHEMATICA, it seems that MATHEMATICA could not recognize it. which also give me an error message as "An unknown box name (FunctionResource`MakeResourceFunctionBoxes) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression." do you have any ideas?

Comment: by the way, I also tried ```IntegrateByParts[Log[x]/x^2, x]``` directly, it will not work either. which just gives an output of the expression itself ```IntegrateByParts[Log[x]/x^2, x]```

Answer (score 1):

From the figure listed above, I tried using the
`In[6]:= \[Integral]x^k \[DifferentialD]P`
The output I got is `Out[6]= P x^k`, and I tried defined P as a function of x, it still will not follow what I want. does anyone have any ideas how I could make the expected integration by parts as `\[Integral]x^k \[DifferentialD]P =  x^k P - \[Integral]k*P*x^(k - 1) \[DifferentialD]x`or the results listed from the above figure?

Sincerely,
Li